# AngularJS HTTP status -1

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, http, http-status-codes

I'm working on offline handling for a angularjs app with cordova (Android & iOS). I wrote an http interceptor, that checks for the status of an http requests, and decides what to do.

I had a working version some month ago, and suddenly this stopped working. I found out that I was checking for a http status of `0`. Now this returns `-1`, but I don't why.

```
responseError: function(response) {
   console.log(response.status); // this returns now -1
}
```

So my questions are:

> - What are the standard http codes **for ajax requests** that define cases like **network unavailable**, **offline**, **timeout**... everything when the server is not reachable (e.g. when you shut down your server in development, your mobile connection breaks, or is too slow and times out...)
> - Is the status code set by the browser, or manipulated by AngularJS?
> - Are this codes the same across every browser? Desktop & mobile?
> - What is the difference between code `0` and `-1`?

Answer (score 1):

There was a change in the more recent versions of angular, with the handling of http status code 0. 
[Here is a github discussion based on the change.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12920)

I hope you have already solved you problem by now!